# AngularJS resource : how to update

Tags: angularjs

I'm using express-resource on the server.
In my AngularJS controller:

```
    var User = $resource('/services/users/:userId', {userId:'@id'},
        { update: {method:'PUT'} }
    );
    $scope.save = function(user) {
        user.$update(function(u) { console.log("User " + u)});
    }
```

The PUT method should go to /services/users/2 but it's actually sent to /services/users
So I get a 404

BTW, the user ID field if UserID (not userId or id) but I don't understand how am I supposed to declare the URL.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, after digging a bit I found

```
var User = $resource('/services/users/:id', {id:'@UserID'},
    { update: {method:'PUT'} }
);
```